# JPA 2 Criteria Day from date

Tags: oracle, select, jpa-2.0

I have a field in a table and that stores a date. I'd like to select all records that which the date is on day 5.

After a lot of research I get the code below:

```
    Predicate dayValue = cb.equal(cb.function("day", Integer.class, test.<Date>get(Test_.dateInit)), now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) );
```

But, I'm using a Oracle database and it doesn't have the function day:

```
[EL Warning]: 2013-01-14 11:51:08.001--UnitOfWork(23011228)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.2.v20101206-r8635): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "DAY": invalid identifier
```

Is there an other way to do this select?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I got a way.

Using the function to_char of oracle in the function method:

```
Predicate dayValue = cb.equal(cb.function("to_char", Integer.class, test.<Date>get(Test_.dateInit),cb.parameter(String.class, "dayFormat")), now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) );
...
q.setParameter("dayFormat", "DD");
```

Answer (score -1):

In Oracle you can use

```
select to_char (date '2013-01-14', 'D') d from dual;
```

to give you the day number, the above will output 1 for Monday

if you want to see Monday just change to

```
select to_char (date '2013-01-14', 'Day') d from dual;
```

the above will output Monday

hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't what I asked.

Comment: I can see you sorted it, an other way is to write a small program to calculate day of the week e.g. in java you can do                        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(yourDate);
int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);